# How to compare database entry and form entry

Tags: c#, compare, compact-database

I'm using C# 2010 Express and Sql Compact. I have two-column table and a form to add a data to save to the table. But I dont want to save same entrys.

For example;

```
Name     City
Sefa     Istanbul
Sefa     New york
Sefa     London
Ben      New York
......
```

is ok but if user want to add another

```
Name     City
Sefa     Istanbul
```

or already available another entry, the program must stop.

I have add this code to my project, but checkcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() command always returns '-1'

```
SqlCeConnection Baglanti = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CeoDatabase.sdf;Password=CeoDB;Persist Security Info=True");
            Baglanti.Open();


            string checkcommand = "SELECT BarAdi, BarSehri FROM Barlar WHERE BarAdi = '"+ Txt_BarAdi.Text +"' AND BarSehri = '"+Txt_BarSehri.Text+"'";
            SqlCeCommand checkcmd = new SqlCeCommand(checkcommand, Baglanti);
            int kontrol = checkcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(kontrol.ToString());
            return;
            if (checkcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bu bilgiler ile kayıtlı bir bar zaten mevcut");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCeCommand Islem = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Barlar(BarAdi,BarSehri)VALUES('" + Txt_BarAdi.Text + "','" + Txt_BarSehri.Text + "')", Baglanti);
                Islem.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("İşlem başarıyla tamamlandı");
            }


            Baglanti.Close();
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? Are you using plain textboxes or using gridview with editing enabled? There are many ways of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it one of the ways

- Either set [Unique](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) Key for that column in Database . When new record will be inserted it will be automatically checked (Preferred)[image]
- Or while Inserting new record check if that city already exist.

If you want to check for exist combination. Do somthing like this (I assume this how you have your data):

```
SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection("your connection string");
string checkcommand = "SELECT [Name], [City] FROM [Tablename]" +
                      "WHERE [Name] == @name AND [City] == @city" ;
SqlCeCommand checkcmd= new SqlCeCommand(checkcommand, cn);
checkcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtBoxName.Text);
checkcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtBoxCity.Text);
cn.Open();
//Check if record already exist
if(checkcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    //It already exist
}
else
{
   //It doesn't exist Insert new record
}
```

Comment: I set both of my columns as Unique;
I can add Sefa - Istanbul but when I try to add Sefa - New york, you know it's not done by this way...

For the second way I want to add more than one people to each city for example Sefa - Istanbul and Ben - Istanbul can be added to database.

Comment: why u setting both your Columns as unique.. your use case dosent have `Name` column with unique values .. you only need `City` column to be unique

Comment: When I set City as unique I'm not able to add more persons to that city

Comment: ok i got it you dont want to have same Combination of Name and City... is that so

Comment: for that too.. Either you can have an Insert trigger to check for such entry or Check for existing combination in your code and then Insert the data

Comment: The question is hot to check for exist combination?

Comment: When  
if (checkcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
Line worked, There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 49,Token in error = = ] exception returned.

Comment: I updatet my question, please check.
Ignore             MessageBox.Show(kontrol.ToString());
            return; lines, I add them for a control when I remove them noting adding to db